# Application Error on Heroku - not specifying the correct port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I am unable to view my running application on Heroku. I'm receiving the standard `Application Error` screen -

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Heroku Logs:

```
2018-06-05T10:50:18.031804+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-06-05T10:50:22.184406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m-k-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=8ba945a9-49a0-4e08-8ec9-2103dd7b207a fwd="174.109.209.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-05T10:50:25.677788+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=m-k-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=65b41c1d-87a7-40d8-8b09-32c39fb9a4fc fwd="174.109.209.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-05T10:50:26.459018+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=m-k-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=a660a55b-d00a-477d-8a2b-7b0b7093410e fwd="174.109.209.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My procfile currently contains:
`web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV`

I changed it to the following to see what would happen, and the Application Error persisted:
`web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`

I believe the problem is that it's not getting the right port, but I'm not able to find a working solution for this on SO.

---

UPDATE (7:10am):

When I run `heroku run rails console` I receive the following logs:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         ... 8070 levels...
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

---

UPDATE (7:17am):
I tried `Restarting all Dynos` on Heroku but it didn't work.

Comment: what ruby version are you using for your local development?

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.3.4p301

Comment: Try using `ruby 2.4` as heroku is using that ruby version.
From your errors it seems to be a ruby version error only.

Comment: That's not solving the problem.  I did `rvm reinstall ruby 2.4`, `rvm use 2.4`, `heroku restart`, then deployed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fixnum` & `Bignum` are now deprecated & should be used `Integer` instead from `Ruby 2.4`. I am also seeing that you are using `rails 4.2.5` which is not compatible with `Ruby 2.4`.

> You would need to upgrade your rails version to atleast `Rails 4.2.8`.

Ref:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27670#issuecomment-272433797